# Options for packaging a RIA app using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ria, rich-internet-application

I'm working on a RIA app based on html and javascript, jquery to be more specific.  I would like to package and run it in on desktops as a standalone application.  I'm looking at mongoose as an option for a simple webserver. What are the front-end options to create such a package.

1. The native browser - Need to determine in each os what the default browser is and launch it.  Besides the app would end up as one of the tabs in a window and would be affected by a misbehaving script on an unrelated page.
2. Packaging with Mozilla Prism -  Seems to be inactive
3. Google Chrome Apps - First, Google Chrome needs to installed by the user.  Next it seems like the app can be installed only through the marketplace and even then the user has to go to the tools section and specify  "Create Application Shortcut". Seems like asking too much from the user.  Is there an option where I can package chrome itself with my app?
4. Titanium Appcelerator -  Seems promising but I'm not sure of the license for desktop apps and I have issues setting up Titanium in my 64 bit machine (ubuntu 10.10) which questions my dependence on Titanium for cross-platform development.

Is there any other option that I can approach?
Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air lets you package an app using the web stack to run as a standalone on a desktop:

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

Comment: Hi jlbruno, Thanks for chipping in.  But from what I see installing adobe air on linux is a pain (especially 64 bit).  (And the my app is mainly for linux, though it is aimed to be cross platform).  Do you have any experience in setting up air for linux?

Comment: Hi, I don't unfortunately. Although they do list themselves as compatible with Fedora Core 12, Ubuntu 9.10, and openSUSE® 11.2

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/systemreqs/